# Is there a GUI which will enable me to query an XML file?

Tags: xml, database

I have an XML file which I'd like to query (read/write) in the same way as I would a relational database. Performance is not a big issue, I just want to be able to load the file and start querying, preferably without having to define a schema. Does anyone know if such software exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're familiar with C# and Linq, [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is the way to go. You can use Linq to Sql and Linq to XML from there.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out [eXist](http://exist.sourceforge.net/), an XML DB with [XQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery) support and an [admin UI](http://exist.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html#sect6).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by read/write but assuming you want an Access-like experience, try the [Oxygen XML Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor.html).

It's a great XML general editor with a lot of support for querying and their [Grid Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor.html#XML_Grid_Editor) does a nice job of allowing you to just *insert/delete row* if there is any recurring data in the XML.

As well as XPath, it also has full [XQuery support](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xquery_editor.html) with GUI to help you write queries.

I've used it for years - I particularly like the license terms and cross-platform GUI which let me use it on any of my machines including Mac.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a GUI, but xmllint has a shell option, which allows you to interact with XML files via XPath. It's quite handy and a little bit similar to browsing a directory structure in Unix. See http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html

Answer (score 0):

Check with baseX XML database GUI which is free and very use full tool to visualize any XML file and you can import the XML as a new database and start querying them

https://docs.basex.org/